# Show divs that start with variable

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

I have a dropdown selector that uses jquery to show/hide divs when selected.

```
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown"
    onchange="refreshPage(this.value);">
    <option <?php if ($ap == 'ATL') print 'selected '; ?> value="ATL">Atlanta</option>
    <option <?php if ($ap == 'MIA') print 'selected '; ?> value="MIA">Miami</option>
    <option <?php if ($ap == 'MCO') print 'selected '; ?> value="MCO">Orlando</option>
</select>
```

Within a div, I have child divs that start with the same characters of the parent as below

```
<div id="ATL">
    Atlanta
    <div id="ATL1">Put output here</div>
    <div id="ATL2">Put output here</div>
    <div id="ATL3">Put output here</div>
</div>

<div id="MIA">
    Miami
    <div id="MIA1">Put output here</div>
    <div id="MIA2">Put output here</div>
    <div id="MIA3">Put output here</div>
</div>
```

The Jquery that I use is

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function showTab( name ) {
            newname = '#' + name ;
            $('div').not(newname).hide();
            $(newname).show();
        }

        $('#dropdown').change( function() {
            showTab( $( this ).val() );
        });

        showTab( $('#dropdown').val() );

    });  // this line was missing 
</script>
```

The problem is that when I make a selection, only the main div will be selected.  Is there anyway that I can include a wildcard after 'name' in the Jquery line

```
 newname = '#' + name ;
```

so that anything starting with name will be displayed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could do it like this:

```
newname = '[id^="' + name + '"]';
```

Which selects elements with the specified attribute (in this case `id`) **starting** with your given string. You can read more about it on [jQuery's Docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `id^=`, this will match ID's beginning with what you specify. For your case, I believe it would look like:

```
$("[id^=" + name + "]")
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use class

```
<div id="MIA" class="MIA">Miami         
<div id="MIA1" class="MIA">Put output here</div>
<div id="MIA2" class="MIA">Put output here</div>
<div id="MIA3" class="MIA">Put output here</div>
</div>
```

and

```
newname = '.' + name ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this slightly differently, only hiding the tab containers essentially, and not all of the divs.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div id="ATL">Atlanta
        <div id="ATL1">Put output here</div>
        <div id="ATL2">Put output here</div>
        <div id="ATL3">Put output here</div>
    </div>
    <div id="MIA">Miami
        <div id="MIA1">Put output here</div>
        <div id="MIA2">Put output here</div>
        <div id="MIA3">Put output here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...

```
function showTab(name) {
    newname = '#' + name;
    $('tabs > div').hide();
    $(newname).show();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dropdown').change(function () {
        showTab($(this).val());
    });
    showTab($('#dropdown').val());
});
```